# Weak solutions for 2D shallow water equations with source termes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, hyperbolic-equations

My question is similar to the one asked in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175027/symmetrizability-of-shallow-water-equations). I am trying to find the weak form solution for the following 2D shallow water equation (SWE) with source terms:
$$
\begin{cases}
 \partial_t h + \partial_x(hu) + \partial_y(hv) = 0\\
 \partial_t(hu) + \partial_x(hu^2 + \frac{gh^2}{2}) + \partial_y(huv)= gh(S_{0,x} - S_{f,x})\\
 \partial_t(hv) + \partial_x(huv) + \partial_y(hv^2 + \frac{gh^2}{2})= gh(S_{0,y} - S_{f,y})
\end{cases}
$$

I have written the system in weak form, but I am struggling to derive the entropy equation to ensure the uniqueness of the weak solutions. I attempted to follow the steps outlined in François Bouchut's textbook, but was unsuccessful. Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please be more precise about what you are looking for and why you believe it is worth attempting a solution. To me, it seems difficult to do anything for arbitrary source terms. Even with a more detailed expression of the boundary conditions and source terms, I doubt that a closed-form solution can be derived in 2D space.

Comment: Thank you @EditPiAf for your useful feedback. I need to solve the weak form of SWEs. I am attempting to derive the entropy equation "only" to ensure the uniqueness for the weak solution. I do not personally know if it would be possible to do this in another way. Would you have any suggestions?Shall I specify the source terms and the BCs and ICs for an arbitrary 2D problem?